# Using IHttpClientFactory to immediately close connections

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm connecting to an API, whos' owner doesn't allow more than 1 request per connection. This is very unfortunate, but I have to work with this.
I could create a new *HttpClient* for each request, but this would leave me vulnerable for socket exhaustion. As such, I'm setting for my *HttpClient*:

```
DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

And getting it from IHttpClientFactory via

```
_httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

Now this mostly works fine, but there is one issue. If I send subsequent calls in a loop, like so:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var request = _requestBuilder.BuildRequest();
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
```

Then this will sometimes fail trying to reuse the old connection before it's closed. So my first question is: why is IHttpClientFactory reusing the old connection if I send the request with a *Connection: close* header?

What's more, I've been looking at netstat and while, unsuprisingly, after creating a new HttpClient for each call I get a bunch of connections in TIME_WAIT status. But for the above ,if it doesn't fail, I get a single connection in CLOSE_WAIT. If I query netstat during runtime of these requests I can see the port is being changed for the current connection, but if a new connection is opened the old one is closed immediately and it doesn't hang in any status. So how is the IHttpClientFactory actually managing this? I couldn't get to close the connection immediately by calling dispose on either *HttpClient* or *HttpResponseMessage*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could create a new HttpClient for each request, but this would leave me vulnerable for socket exhaustion.

I recommend you use an `HttpClient` for each request. If the server honors `ConnectionClose` (which it seems to be doing), then you won't be in any more danger of socket exhaustion than you would be using `IHttpClientFactory`.

For modern HTTP servers (ones that allow multiple requests, like was added in HTTP 1.1... *in 1997*), there's a danger of socket exhaustion because the clients normally close their sockets, which enter `TIME_WAIT` state. So `IHttpClientFactory` avoids the socket exhaustion *by reusing the sockets*. But in your case, the server won't allow socket reuse, so `IHttpClientFactory` is just going to add complexity without providing any benefit.

> DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;

Setting this for HTTP connections means that the *server* closes the socket connection, which means that your local socket enters `CLOSE_WAIT` rather than `TIME_WAIT`. Here's the diagram if this isn't clear; it's from Stevens' TCP/IP Illustrated:

[image: TCP/IP state diagram]

> Then this will sometimes fail trying to reuse the old connection before it's closed. So my first question is: why is IHttpClientFactory reusing the old connection if I send the request with a Connection: close header?

The whole point of `IHttpClientFactory` is to reuse connections. AFAIK the factory does not have any special handling around `ConnectionClose`, so it *assumes* the socket is still viable so it keeps it around. Then it tries to use that socket again.

The "sometimes" part of the failure could be due to a race condition: I suspect the factory is doing something like checking whether the socket is closed, and if it is, creating a new one; and if not, returning a socket (in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state), which will then fail.

> But for the above ,if it doesn't fail, I get a single connection in CLOSE_WAIT.

I would expect the factory to keep its socket connection around, since it's not aware of `ConnectionClose`.

> If I query netstat during runtime of these requests I can see the port is being changed for the current connection, but if a new connection is opened the old one is closed immediately and it doesn't hang in any status.

Connections cannot change ports. I expect the old connection is kept around until it is closed by the factory when it determines the connection isn't viable, and then the factory immediately creates a new one.

> I couldn't get to close the connection immediately by calling dispose on either HttpClient or HttpResponseMessage

Technically, the thing that the factory reuses is not `HttpClient`, but the last `HttpMessageHandler` in the chain of handlers wrapped by the `HttpClient`. And for factory-created clients, this isn't disposed when you dispose `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thanks. If I know that every connection is finished after 1 request, can I set my application / HttpClient to send the FIN message back to the server after I receive one from them? Or is it not feasible?
Btw. I was thinking that's what happens to these connections "being switched" with the IHttpClientFactory that I described as "changing ports" - apologies for wrong technical term on that. I assume they would be shown by the netstat if kept around, right?

Comment: The TCP layer will handle the FIN packets for you. It's just that server-initiated closes are not common, so that's why the factory doesn't think to detect them.

Comment: I see. If the server in the response would send a header Connection: close, would the tcp layer send FIN back to the server to close this connection immediately?

Comment: No. The TCP layer doesn't interpret HTTP headers.